# How to find the total number of values for a particular Key in Multimap C++

Tags: c++, multimap

I have created a multimap with key as the Mod value and VALUE as the number being modded. Just like a hash table.

```
vector<int> A{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int n=A.size();
multimap<int,int> mymap;

int sqvalue=sqrt(n);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   int temp=A[i]%sqvalue;
   mymap.insert(pair<int,int>(temp,A[i]));
}
```

Q1. How to obtain the total number of VALUES for all the KEYS ? e.g How many numbers exist in Key no.2.?
Q2. How to print all the values wrt to its Keys ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [equal_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range), which returns a range containg all the values with given key.

```
auto rng = myMap.equal_range(key);
// e.g. sum of the valuse
auto sum = std::accumulate(rng.first, rng.second, 0);
// Or print
for(auto it = rng.first; it != rng.second; ++it)
      std::cout<<elm->second;
```

Comment: Its giving me this error
`main.cpp:31:30: error: no member named 'begin' in
      'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int,
      int> >, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>
      > >'
    int sum = accumulate(rng.begin(), rng.end(), 0);
                         ~~~ ^ `

`main.cpp:31:43: error: no member named 'end' in
      'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int,
      int> >, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>
      > >'
    int sum = accumulate(rng.begin(), rng.end(), 0);
                                      ~~~ ^
`